# Relationship between Interface Speed and Processing times

Tags: cpu, network-interface, delay

I have a question regarding processing time delays. I want to know: is there a relationship between the rate of data packets received and their processing time at the receiving host, or is the processing time completely random? I mean if I'm using the same computer and I'm receiving data on a 1G interface and another time I'm receiving data at the 10G interface, is the processing time necessarily less at the 1G? and why?

Note: this is a theoretical question, no bottlenecks, no drops, no offloading.

Comment: Since it's theoretical I could say anything and it would almost be true, since its theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

In short: If you start processing as soon as you receive data **and** you can process data faster than you receive it, the total processing time will be smaller on the faster interface. But this is almost never the case.

- **If** the processing speed is faster than the reception speed:

  - **If** you start processing when you receive the first bits: You will end the processing right after receiving the last bit, so the processing time depends on the reception time, and the elapsed time between start and end of processing will be **smaller for a faster interface**.
  - **Else** if you start processing after receiving the last bit: The processing time is **not linked** to the reception speed.
- **Else** if the processing speed is slower than the reception speed:

  - **If** you start processing when you receive the first bits: You will end the processing after reception is over, **regardless of the interface speed**.
  - **Else** if you start processing after receiving the last bit: The processing time is **not linked** to the reception speed.
- **Else** (Processing speed between reception speed on one interface and reception speed on the other interface)

  - **If** you start processing when you receive the first bits: The processing won't be as fast against the slower interface than against the faster interface (it will have to wait for upcoming data), so the elapsed time between start and end of processing will be **smaller for a faster interface**.
  - **Else** if you start processing after receiving the last bit: The processing time is **not linked** to the reception speed.

Note: Most of the time, the reception of the packet will  be encapsulated behind a utility forwarding you complete packets after reception, which means the processing time is **not linked** to the reception speed.